# Class to define result of 2 joined objects

Tags: php, oop, object

I have three classes to define objects: `Users`, `Members` and `Projects`.

- The `User` class defines details such as `id`, `email_address` and
  `name`.
- The `Member` class defines details such as the `id`, `user_id`,
  `project_id` and `datetime_accepted`.
- The `Project` class defines details such as `id` and `title` - this
  isn't important though.

The system has `Users` and `Projects`. A `Member` is a `User` working on a `Project`. In other words, the `Member` class defines a link between two objects.

**My question is this:**

I want to get a list of members belonging to a certain project, and I want to collect variables from both classes (`Member` and `User` - such as `User`:`name` and `Member`:`datetime_accepted`) in my result set.

Do I need to define a new class that has all the variables from both classes, or is there some other, more efficient structure that I can use to handle this neatly and in an object oriented manner?

Answer (score 1):

You can easly cast StdObject into array by:

```
$result = array_merge((array)$user, (array)$member);
```

then you will have an array of variables you need. Add this to new function in Project class,
or consider using Member as child of User class.

Comment: I think using Member and a child of User might be a better approach for my implementation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When working with Active Record Models, you would generally have a method in one object to get related objects.  If you wanted to simplify the SQL to one query, you're getting away from the Active Record Model.  This is fine, it just changes the way you approach the problem.

What I have done in the past is one of two approaches:

1. To add 'virtual properties' to an AR, for example, my Login (User) class has a property "Roles" which is populated by a JOIN in its standard loading query.
2. To create a Report object which I extend for more complex situations.  The Report subclasses have a property that is the multi-table query, and other properties which represent parameters for the WHERE clause.  The class produces an array of arrays.

Comment: Interesting. I'm relatively new to this so your advice is really appreciated. I might create a Member variable in my User class and see how I get on with that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing to solve this issue was to create a `Project` and a `User` object inside the `Member`. The objects were created when the member was constructed. Works okay.